# New line textfield- iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to put a new line in a `textfield` placeholder? something like:

```
comment1= [[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame2]autorelease];
comment1.placeholder = @"Write maximum 200 \r characters here";
```

Comment: Can you use a UITextView instead? They are designed for using multiple lines.

Comment: Unless you do some pointless crazy stuff then **NO**. You would just be wasting your time you might as well use `UITextView`.

Answer (score 4):

`UITextField` is meant to show only single line. If you wish to show multiple line text you'll have to use `UITextView`. Or, you can use `UILabel` and set the number of lines property. In iPhone "\n" is new line character. However, it won't work with `UITextField`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UITextView` for multiline text

Answer (score -1):

UITextField does not have any property or facility to create new line in it. You can use UITextView instead. Here is the code sample..

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{ //Enter your code here }}
```